# Binary Sequence for activity of a user

Tags: python, binary

I have a binary sequence for the activity period  of a user. There is a "0" when he was not active on this day and a "1" when he was. I want to proof if he was active not less than two times a week, so there have to be at least two ones in every 7 positions of the sequence. Can anyone help me to implement that idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with string or list, too:

```
days="110000000000110011"
#days=['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1']

for d in range(0,len(days),7): 
    print(d//7,days[d:d+7].count("1"))

#In the output, the first number is the week number:
0 2
1 2
2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can just add these values and check if sum is bigger or equal than 2.

Here is code:

```
activity_list = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

def is_active(activity_list: list, minimum_active_days: int):
    return sum(activity_list) >= minimum_active_days

print(is_active(activity_list, 2))
>>> True
```

Answering to comment:

> And what can I do if the list is much longer than 7 and I want to know
>   if in every 7 entries the sum is bigger or equal than 2?

Then you should slice your list to get values that you want to check.

```
# some_long_list - stores more than 7 values
for i in range(len(some_long_list) -7):
    print(f"Is active in period: from {i}, to {i+7}")
    print(is_active(some_long_list[i:i+7], 2))
```

Comment: And what can I do if the list is much longer than 7 and I want to know if in every 7 entries the sum is bigger or equal than 2?